# Vaadin Select - fields changed inside binder's apply do not write changes to bean from item

Tags: drop-down-menu, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Using Vaadin 14.7.0.
Inside a CRUD editor (Enhanced CRUD Editor) I'm building various fields, amongst which I have a Select.

The Select is initialized with a list of options but I'm also trying to change the items from CRUD form edit to CRUD form edit depending on changes from my underlying database so that the user can select new values.

```
BindingBuilder<Item, SelectOption> bindingBuilder = binder.forField(s);
if (prop.isMandatory()) {
    bindingBuilder.asRequired(requiredI18n);
}

bindingBuilder.bind(new ValueProvider<Item, SelectOption>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public SelectOption apply(final Item item) {

        ListPropertyDefinition lp = ((ListPropertyDefinition)prop);
        Serializable currentValue = item.get(lp.getName());

        Collection<SelectOption> sOptions = null;
        if (lp.getSelectOptions() != null) {
            ListDataProvider<SelectOption> ldp = (ListDataProvider)s.getDataProvider();
            sOptions = ldp.getItems();
        } else {
            sOptions = getNewOptions(item, prop.getName());
            s.setItems(sOptions);
        }

        return new SelectOption("N/A", currentValue);
    }
}, new Setter<Item, SelectOption>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void accept(final Item bean, final SelectOption fieldvalue) {
        bean.set(prop.getName(), fieldvalue != null ? fieldvalue.getValue() : null);
    }
});
```

Now, if the s.setItems(sOptions) branch is being called then the Select field gets populated with the new values sent by the backend but when I'm saving the item the value that I get is null, regardless of what I select in the select field.
This does not happen when I do not change the items in the select field (i.e. if branch).

I did some debugging for comparing 2 select fields - one that changes its values on the fly and one that has values that don't change... from what I could see the field that has values changing on the fly has a null buffered value as seen in the attached image:

[image: select with items changed on the fly]

vs the field that does not have its values modified in the binder's apply method:
[image]

Not sure if what I'm doing is the right way of "refreshing" a select field's values and / or what should I do so that I get the selected value back in the bean on CRUD form save.

Comment: Have you implemented the usual suspects for equals and hashcode for SelectOption?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately with no luck.

Comment: How you have implemented them, see more here: https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/2666

Comment: I implemented as per the above example but no luck. My gut feeling is that the value not being written in the bean from the CRUD form has something to do with the fields' "resetPending" attribute. If you look at the above pictures - both taken in debug mode - one for a select field with "static" values (i.e. values that were not changed inside the binder's ValueProvider's apply method) and the other for a SelectField that has its values altered within the ValueProvider - you`ll see that the first picture shows "resetPending=true" for the Select while the other says resetPending = false.

Comment: @TatuLund looking into the com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(T, boolean, boolean) method I see that this method gets called every time I change my input in the select field and this is what I expect to be happening. The bufferedValues gets assigned to the newValue field as per my UI selection. The problem is that this value never gets written back into the bean as I'm saving my CRUD form and, as mentioned above, I think this has something to do with the field being marked as "resetPending=true".

Comment: Could you simplify your code by replacing anonymous inner classes as lambdas.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue after seeing that it was related to the sequence in which the crud editor was calling the writeItemChanges ... just before doing that there was a call to reset all fields before closing the crud editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing things in overly complicated manner. Based on your code I think your principal challenge is how to set empty selection to be "N/A"

For that you simply need to enable empty selection to be allowed. You need to have one placeholder item for empty selection, for which you generate "N/A" as caption. Then you can just do:

```
    Binder<Item> binder = new Binder<>();
    Select<SelectOption> select = new Select<>();
    ...
    select.setEmptySelectionAllowed(true);
    select.setEmptySelectionCaption("N/A");
    binder.forField(s).bind(Item::getProperty,Item::setProperty);


public class SelectOption {
   ...   
}

// Make the item bean also to follow POJO convention
public class Item {

    private SelectOption property;
    public SelectOption getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
    public void setProperty(SelectOption property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
        
}
```